# Geofirestore combined with

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am trying to combine Geofirestore with "Compound (AND) queries".

The original code example (from documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#web-modular-api)

```
const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
const promises = [];
for (const b of bounds) {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, 'cities'), 
    orderBy('geohash'), 
    startAt(b[0]), 
    endAt(b[1]));

  promises.push(getDocs(q));
}

// Collect all the query results together into a single list
const snapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Say I also want to query documents within a specific date range e.g. birthday, changing the query to:

```
const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
const promises = [];
for (const b of bounds) {
  const q = query(
         'myCollection',
         orderBy('birthday'),
         where('birthday', '<=', maxDate),
         where('birthday', '>=', minDate),          
         orderBy('geohash'), 
         startAt(b[0]), 
         endAt(b[1])
         );
   
  promises.push(getDocs(q));
}
   
// Collect all the query results together into a single list
const snapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
```

With the original code Firestore returns the expected test document, but if I add birthday as query params Firestore returns 0 documents. I seem to be unable to understand why that is. Does anyone have an insight on this? Any help is appreciated.

BTW! If the query is only on birthday, the expected test document is returned

Comment: Did you create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes I did. The browser automatically tells if the index is required. It provides the URL to create the new index.

Comment: The last query on your code doesn't filter on a geohash value from what I can tell. Are you sure that is the completely query that is not working?

Comment: What makes you think the last query does not filter on geohash? (sorry, I just updated the 2nd code example with my own birthday criteria)

Comment: You're not filtering on `b` in the loop of that last code sample ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: My mistake :( I refactored the code and tried different approaches, hence forgot to copy all code required to demonstrate the example. I have now updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Firestore query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Combining that with knowledge the `startAt` and `endAt` are just another way to write `>` and `<` conditions, and it becomes clear that there's no way to filter both by geohash range and `birthday` range in a single query.

---

If you store `birthDate` in a format that supports equality checks and the range of dates is small enough, you **may** be able to use an `in` condition for it. For example, say you care about birth **year** you'd store it as a separate field, you could do:

```
where('birthyear', 'in', [1970, 1971, 1972])
```

---

To learn more about why this sort of query currently isn't possible on Firestore, I recommend watching my talk from some years ago: [Querying Firestore based on geographic location or distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

Also check out the questions to some previous answers on the topic:

- [Is it possible to query Firebase Firestore by both a location and age range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812030/is-it-possible-to-query-firebase-firestore-by-both-a-location-and-age-range)
- [Is there a way I can combine a GeoFireStore query with a normal Firestore query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572432/is-there-a-way-i-can-combine-a-geofirestore-query-with-a-normal-firestore-query)
- [Firestore query timestamp and geohash in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700540/firestore-query-timestamp-and-geohash-in-one-query)

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. That makes so much sense. Thanks for pointing to the limitations and an interesting approach with the separate birthday field. I will look at your talk on this topic. Again, thank you :)